# how to split two tubes intersecting in a closed double curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be two tubes intersecting in a closed double curve. Let $X$ be an operation which split the two tubes so that the intersection between them becomes empty. The question is what kind of operation can be $X$? I think attaching 1-handle is possible.  If we attach handle,  then we introduce two branch points in the closed double curve.  Am I right?  If so, Is there any other possiblity to $X$.

Answer (score 0):

If minimum variable skew distance between their axis in 3 space is S,

radii of circular tubes R and r, then

$$ S < R + r $$ is for intersection,

$$  S > R + r $$ for non-intersection/empty set and

$$  S = R + r $$ for tangential point contact.

So either increase $S$ or reduce $R+r$